# Magento is using the default tax rates for NY and CA

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, taxes

I am having a problem with my magento 1.9.1 deployment.  I have created custom tax rates:

[image]

However, I just received two orders with taxes charged based on the default magento tax rules:

Order from New York.  (No taxes should be charged here)
[image]

Order form California. (Should be charged 8.5%)
[image]

Both of these orders are using the default tax settings out of the box.  I'm not sure where these values are coming from.  I have checked the database tables and don't see anything there.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using rricketts tax_rates.csv file to import all the correct tax rates.

[tax_rates.csv](http://rricketts.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/magento_tax_rates.zip)

Also take a look at 
http://rricketts.com/magento-us-tax-csv-file-all-50-states/

Comment: That won't work.  My client only wants to charge tax in the above areas.  I have entered them correctly, but somehow, they are pulling the default values for CA and NY

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tax Rule]
Probably used an incorrect Customer Tax Class or Product Tax Class in Tax Rule

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to select tax rates withing tax rules setting.

You need to go Sales -> Tax -> Manage tax rules.

If you have some rules already as default Not Logged In - Taxable Goods     Not Logged-in   and Retail Customer - Taxable Good - Rate 1 you need to go into that rule and select tax rates there

or if you don't have any tax rules just create a new ones for the retail customers and not logged in customers and select tax rates there.

[image]

[image]

[image: tax rule edit]